# AJAX & JQuery load with anchors

Tags: jquery, ajax, load, anchor

i have the next code to load content from external page.html using JQuery:

SCRIPT:

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
$(
function(){
var jContent = $( "#content" );

$( "nav ul li a").click(function( objEvent ){
var jLink = $( this ); ...
```

HTML

```
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="page1.html">Page 1</a></li>
<li><a href="page2.html">Page 2</a></li>
<li><a href="page3.html">Page 3</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>


<div id="content">Here load content</div>
```

The script works fine, but... i want some content load them to one particular anchor ( page1.html#anchor )

http://www.libelulastudio.com/demo/ajax/01/

**What should I add to my script? Thanks**

///////////////////////

Hello finally solved with the following code:

```
<script> $(document).ready(function(){ $("a#dos").click(function(){
      $("#content").load("page2.html", function(responseTxt,statusTxt,xhr){ 
        if(statusTxt=="success")
        $(function() {
    $(document).scrollTop( $("#p2").offset().top );  });
        if(statusTxt=="error")
        alert("Error: "+xhr.status+": "+xhr.statusText);
      });
    }); ...
```

HTML

```
<a href="#" id="dos">Go to Product 2</a>

<div id="content">... content ... </div>
```

Comment: what exactly you want to do.?

Comment: if I run my link to an anchor not working: page1.html#anchor

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
<script lang='javascript'>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.ajaxload').click(function(){
                $('#content_div').load($(this).attr('id')+'.html');
            });
        });
</script>

<nav>
    <ul>
       <li><a class='ajaxload' href="javascript:void(0)" id='page1'>Page 1</a></li>
       <li><a class='ajaxload' href="javascript:void(0)" id='page2'>Page 2</a></li>
       <li><a class='ajaxload' href="javascript:void(0)" id='page3'>Page 3</a></li>
       <li><a href='#page4_content'>Page 4</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<div id='content_div'>
    <!--Here your content gets loaded-->
</div>
<div id='page4_content'>
    <!--Page 4 content here-->
</div>
```

More info at [jQuery AJAX load()](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_load.asp)

Comment: HI your code work fine, now, as i can do to load content and also go to a particular segment as a anchor example: page1#anchor

Answer (score 1):

According to your Last Comment you need to pass `event` as argument inside `click event handler` and then call `preventDefault` so anchor will redirect you, you have already passed `objEvent.`

So code will look like below

```
$( "nav ul li a").click(function( objEvent ){
   objEvent.preventDefault();
```